# Strtok with 2 Delims in C

Tags: c, split, strtok

I want to split a char array into words in C. However, there are two different delims. Delims are ';' and '|'. The delims don't have a regular order, they're given in a mixed order. Let me show you.

`char str[] = "apple|lemon;banana;pear|strawberry";`

output should be: `char str2 = "apple lemon banana pear strawberry";`

I have no idea about this topic, if you could help me I would be very happy.

Comment: Writing a simple `strtok()` replacement using a `switch` is super easy. Give it a shot. Tip: Iterate over characters using a pointer.

Comment: Doesn't `strtok` already do this thing for you with `strtok(string, ",|")`?

Comment: Your data uses `|` and `;` — your text claims `|` and `,`.  Be careful to be self-consistent, please.

Comment: @aybkcn you should read up on how `strtok` works. The second argument is not one delimiter, it is a list of delimiters, and each character is a single delimiter. The duplicate has more info on this, you should see it.